# Can I apply `tmux` to a bash script?

Tags: linux, tmux, raspberry-pi, bash-script, raspbian

Is it possible for me to use `tmux` to SSH into a Raspberry Pi, run a Bash script, and then leave the session (from my laptop), while the Raspberry Pi continues to run the script?

Comment: Please explain carefully where `tmux` and `ssh` should run, and where the script should run (and what it would be doing, in rough outline at least). There are several ways in which your question can be interpreted (run `tmux` here, under it run a script that `ssh`s into the Raspberry Pi, ...)

Comment: Sorry. Here Goes.:)  From my laptop, I would SSH into the Pi. Then, I'd run `tmux`(on the Pi), run the bash script(on the Pi), leave `tmux`(on the Pi), and then leave the SSH session (on my laptop). At this point, I want the Pi to keep _keep running_ the bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use `ssh` to log into your box. Run `tmux` on that box. Run you script inside `tmux`. Detach your `tmux` session and log out.

Later you can use ssh to log into your box. Reattach your running `tmux` session and watch you script while it still executes.

Comment: So you can run a bash script just like any normal terminal command?

Comment: yes. tmux allows you to detach the whole session together with whatever runs inside.

Comment: How do I reattach to tmux to check it's progress?

Comment: oh, come on, please show some effort of your own. google will give you [lots](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course) [of](http://www.dayid.org/os/notes/tm.html) [instructions](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/intro-to-tmux/).

Comment: Actually I posted that, and then just figured it out on my own (without the help of google). But yes, you're right.